# Android: Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-memory, java-memory-leaks

I am using the code below in my `activity class`:

```
public static Activity list_Addresses_Activity;
```

And in my `onCreate` I used from this :

```
list_Addresses_Activity = this;
```

But it throws an error stated below:

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)
```

I need to use it from `static` because I will use from this in my `Service class`.

My `CloseActivies.class` :

```
public class CloseActivies {
    Activity a;
    Activity b;
    Activity c;

    protected void CLSActivities(Activity ListAddresses, Activity ListOrder, Activity SendReports) {
        a = ListAddresses;
        b = ListOrder;
        c = SendReports;
        if (ListAddressesActivity.FlagLiveAddress && a != null) {
            Log.e("ADASFSDAGWEG", "X");
            a.finish();
            ListAddressesActivity.FlagLiveAddress = false;
        }
        if (ListOrderActivity.FlagLiveOrder && b != null) {
            Log.e("ADASFSDAGWEG", "Y");
            b.finish();
            ListOrderActivity.FlagLiveOrder = false;
        }
        if (SendReportsActivity.FlagSendReport && c != null) {
            Log.e("ADASFSDAGWEG", "Z");
            c.finish();
            SendReportsActivity.FlagSendReport = false;
        }
    }

    protected void CLSActivities() {
        if (ListAddressesActivity.FlagLiveAddress && a != null) {
            Log.e("ADASFSDAGWEG", "X");
            a.finish();
            ListAddressesActivity.FlagLiveAddress = false;
        }
        if (ListOrderActivity.FlagLiveOrder && b != null) {
            Log.e("ADASFSDAGWEG", "Y");
            b.finish();
            ListOrderActivity.FlagLiveOrder = false;
        }
        if (SendReportsActivity.FlagSendReport && c != null) {
            Log.e("ADASFSDAGWEG", "Z");
            c.finish();
            SendReportsActivity.FlagSendReport = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because the static variables are present in class area and not within specific object. Thus, even though the object is freed, the static variable occupies space in memory

Comment: Can you give little more info as to why you need the activity instance in your Service class?

Comment: @Abhishek V . My code is huge. sorry.

Comment: @AbhishekV : I think Jo wants to access some variables of Activity from service.

Comment: I need to finish() activities that are opened.I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will cause a memory leak as your service class is working on a separate thread and passing a static reference to your  activity will keep the instance in memory even if the activity is dismissed and not garbage collected, a safer way to do this is passing a reference of your activity as a parameter to your service and storing it in a weakreference something like this

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    private final WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    public static void startActionFoo(Context context) {
        mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();
        if(context != null) {
            //do your work as since context is not null means
            //activity is still present and if activity is dismissed
            //context will come null 
        }
    }
}
```

If you need activity reference for one of its static variable you can pass it in intent extras, or you want to call a static function of activity, a broadcast receiver would be a better choice to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting service from activity and use some data of activity in that service. You can pass them in intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", "some_value");
    startService(intent);
```